# Toggling a TextView visibility on click

Tags: android, textview

I want to toggle textView on click. [image]

```
val targetView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.targetText)
targetView.text = 'example'
targetView.setOnClickListener {
  if (it.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
    it.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
  } else {
    it.visibility = View.VISIBLE
  }
}
```

But once I clicked and visibility of text was changed to invisible, then I can not click this again.

Comment: So change your plan and toggle visibility by clicking a button or some other view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Suggestion**: How about creating a view behind the text and make use of the view for toggle triggering instead of text.

i.e. `onViewClicked { toggleTextVisibility() }`

Answer (score 0):

Store the text of the textview in a temporary string. Instead of toggling the visibility, set the text to null and then back to what it was using the temp variable.

```
String final tempText = "your text"
```

then

```
targetView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener) {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        if (view.getText() == null) {
            view.setText(tempText);
        } else {
            view.setText("   ");   
        }
     });
}
```

just make sure your textview on the layout properties has a set *minWidth* and not *wrap_content* as it will disappear when you set the text to null